# Node.js app H10 deployment error on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to run a node app on heroku, I got this message:

```
Process exited with status 137
2015-08-21T15:19:16.278225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-refuge-1097.herokuapp.com request_id=3d934205-ea72-44f2-9dd0-4d5aa1521d8e fwd="77.132.40.135" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

there my server.js file

```
  hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || 'localhost',
    port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000,
    publicDir = process.argv[2] || __dirname + '/public';

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("/index.html");
});
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
app.use(errorHandler({
  dumpExceptions: true,
  showStack: true
}));
app.listen(port, hostname);
```

My Procfile

`web: node server.js`

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.1.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.1.2",
    "errorhandler": "^1.0.1",
    "method-override": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
     "node": "0.12.4",
      "npm": "2.10.1"
   }
}
```

I'm trying to figure where the problem come from, but I don't have any ideas.

Comment: What do your logs say above `Process exited with status 137`?

Comment: `2015-08-21T17:06:54.680279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command node server.js 2015-08-21T17:06:57.915353+00:00 app[web.1]: salsa server showing /app/public listening at http://localhost:51650
2015-08-21T17:07:55.260958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-08-21T17:07:55.260958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-08-21T17:07:56.072665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
`       this my logs

Answer (score 1):

This is the root problem: `Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch 2015-08-21T17:07:55.260958+00:00 heroku[web.1]`

You're binding to `localhost`, which means the app will only accept loopback connections. When Heroku probes it to see if it's successfully bound to `$PORT`, it hasn't, because nothing can reach it on `localhost`. You can fix that by just removing the `hostname` bit:

```
app.listen(port);
```